# Software to generate graphs with specific properties.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, math-software, programming

Does anyone know if there is any software that can generate graphs and compute their chromatic polynomials?

For example, say I want to generate all simple graphs on 8 vertices with 16 edges with clique number 5 and have their chromatic polynomials computed (or at least know the specific number of proper $\lambda$-colorings for a specific $\lambda$). Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Morgan_Rodgers Thank you for your response. I was just giving a specific example before. In general, what I would like to do is have all graphs on n vertices and m edges with possibly an additional property (say clique number k) generated for me, up to isomorphism. I realize that there will be a lot of graphs the larger n is, but I just want to check small examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it will be better to use sage. I had to wait a minute for sage to generate the 1312 graphs with 8 vertices and 16 edges, but it took no time to filter out the 94 graphs with clique number 5, and no time to compute the chromatic polynomials.

The program geng in the nauty package would generate the graphs much more quickly. But you still have to determine clique numbers
and chromatic polynomials and I don't think this is part of nauty's skill set - it didn't use to be, but I haven't checked for a while.

Once you're looking at graphs on more than 8 vertices, it would
be much better to produce them using geng and then read them into sage. 
[And it would even better to follow Gordon Royle’s comment!]

Comment: Sage can now do nauty: g8 = [g for g in graphs.nauty_geng('8 16') if g.clique_number() == 5] will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful suggestions! I was dreading having to download nauty since it does not come with a graphical interface. Is there a way to take this list of graphs and obtain a list of their chromatic polynomial values at, say $\lambda=5$?